# Default jinja macro template parameter in airflow dag

Tags: python, airflow

How do I make an airflow dag to receive a parameter and its default value would be its logical date

```
# Define the DAG
dag = DAG(
    dag_id="test",
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    params={"date_param": "{{ ds }}" }
)

# Define the BashOperator task
print_param_task = BashOperator(
    task_id="print_param",
    bash_command='echo "{{ params.date_param }}"',
    dag=dag
)
```

This would print me the string itself "{{ ds }}". I want to be the default the value of logical_date if nothing is passed in the config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
dag = DAG(
    dag_id="aaadfggfdafg",
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule_interval="@daily",
    params={"date_param": "dummydefaultvalue" }
)

# Define the BashOperator task
print_param_task = BashOperator(
    task_id="print_param",
    bash_command='echo "{{ ds if params.date_param == "dummydefaultvalue" else params.date_param}}"',
    dag=dag
)
```